# How to set a time condition to skip operation in for loops in R

Tags: r

I would like to set a time limit for operations in a for loop in R.

Specifically, my idea is that if a operation exceeds a pre-specified time limit the loop doesn't stop but it passes to the next iteration.

Example:

```
time_limit = 5 minutes    
for(i in 1:4){
        possible if statement (e.g if time operation X on element i > 5 minutes, continue the loop with next element)
        operation 1
        operation 2
        operation 3
        }
```

I am aware that the code below is bad witeen, but I hope it helps to better understand my idea.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, based on a combination of `tryCatch` and `R.utils::withTimeout`:

```r
library(R.utils)

for (i in 1:3)
{
  tryCatch(
    expr = {
      withTimeout(Sys.sleep(10), timeout = 1)
    }, 
    TimeoutException = function(msg) cat("Timeout. Skipping.\n")
  )
  
  cat("Printing current i = ", i, "\n")
}

#> Timeout. Skipping.
#> Printing current i =  1 
#> Timeout. Skipping.
#> Printing current i =  2 
#> Timeout. Skipping.
#> Printing current i =  3
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need something that doesn't stop the loop. For instance in your example if the time of print(7) is greater than 1 second than continue to print(8). I need something to skip operations that exceeds a defined time but not stop the loop.

Comment: Please, see my updated solution, @Giordano, which does what you want, I guess.